# Как правильно подключить и скомпилировать библиотеку с github в среде разработки VS

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, c99

Подскажите как правильно скомпилировать или подключить библиотеку для использования https://github.com/zyantific/zydis

Использую среду разработки Visual Studio 2015.

Ищу быстрый дизассемблер для подсчета длины инструкции, если будут советы или предпочтения, заранее благодарю :)

Comment: скорее всего, Вам нужно будет исправить все "ошибки". Библиотека требует С99. И хотя этому стандарту 18 лет, студия даже 2015 [не до конца его поддерживает](https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/hh567368.aspx#c99table).

Comment: Открыл проект в 2017 студии. Все скопилилось, и похоже все работает (то, что я смог проверить)

Comment: @KoVadim не могли бы Вы поподробнее описать, как правильно добавить исходные файлы в проект и скомпилировать. Я так понимаю Вы воспользовались CMakeLists.txt, к сожалению никогда так не делал и не совсем понимаю как правильно его подключать.

Comment: я запустил студи, выбрал открыть -> открыть папку с проектом. Дальше cmake автоматом подхватился и сгенерировался проект. Осталось только нажать Build All